# click listview item to start new activity does not work

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

i am newbie in xamarin android app in c#. i have created page activity which intends to fill listview with array named plays.it successfully shows listview with array items. when i click on listview item nothing happen. it should start new activity depending upon position of item. I think there is problem with **listv.itemclick event handler.**
the pageActivity is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;


namespace smartapp
{
    [Activity(Label = "PageActivity")]
    public class PageActivity : Activity
    {
        ListView listv;
        ArrayAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList Plays;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Pages);

            getData();

            listv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listv);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, Plays);
            listv.Adapter = adapter;

            listv.FastScrollEnabled = true;


            // Create your application here



        listv.ItemClick+= (object sender,AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)=>{


            Intent myintent;
            switch(Plays[e.Position])
            {

            case 0:
            myintent=new Intent(this,typeof(HelpActivity));
            StartActivity(myintent);
            break;
        case 1:
            myintent=new Intent(this,typeof(IslamActivity));
        StartActivity(myintent);
            break;
        case 2:
            myintent=new Intent(this,typeof(AllPagesActivity));
        StartActivity(myintent);
            break;

            }
        };


            }



        private void getData()
        {
            Plays = new ArrayList();
            Plays.Add("Care Center");
            Plays.Add("Real Islam");
            Plays.Add("All Pages");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem according to me is with your Switch it should be something like this:

```
switch(e.Position)   
{

    case 0:
        myintent=new Intent(this,typeof(HelpActivity));
        StartActivity(myintent);
        break;
    case 1:
        myintent=new Intent(this,typeof(IslamActivity));
    StartActivity(myintent);
        break;
    case 2:
        myintent=new Intent(this,typeof(AllPagesActivity));
    StartActivity(myintent);
        break;

 }
```

Comment: very thanks sir  for help..it works fine when changed to switch(e.Position)

Comment: Sure no problem brother, also i am not sir :)